# html2canvas and jsPDF : send generated pdf as email attachment

Tags: php, ajax, jspdf, html2canvas

I have created a function to take screenshot of current webpage and save it as PDF using html2canvas and jsPDF. Following is my code for it:

```
<script>
 function downloadpdf(){
    html2canvas(document.body,
        {
            onrendered: function(canvas){
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                var doc = new jsPDF('p','mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
                doc.save($.now()+'.pdf');

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

By using the above code, I am able to download the file and save it locally. 
But I want to directly send the generated pdf by email using php script.

Following is the code for posting image in php script where it will be sent as email:

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                $.post("sendimage.php", 
                {
                    data: imgData
                }, function (response,status) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
```

But how to post the generated pdf in `data` parameter?

Kindly, recommend any solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the `PHP` code -

```
function MailWithAttachment($to, $subject, $message, $senderMail, $senderName, $files){

    $from = $senderName." <".$senderMail.">"; 
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 

    // preparing attachments
    if(count($files) > 0){
        for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
            if(is_file($files[$i])){
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                $fp =    @fopen($files[$i],"rb");
                $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($files[$i]));
                @fclose($fp);
                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"\n" . 
                "Content-Description: ".basename($files[$i])."\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($files[$i]).";\n" . 
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
    $returnpath = "-f" . $senderMail;

    //send email
    $mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath); 

    //function return true, if email sent, otherwise return fasle
    if($mail){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }
}


if(!empty($_POST['data'])){

    //email variables
    $to = 'to-email@email.com';
    $from = 'from-email@email.com';
    $from_name = 'PDF FIle';

    //attachment files path array
    $file = base64_decode($_POST['data']);

    $subject = 'PHP Email with attachment'; 
    $html_content = '<h1>PHP Email with attachment</h1>';

    //call MailWithAttachment() function and pass the required arguments
    $send_email = MailWithAttachment($to,$subject,$html_content,$from,$from_name,$file);

    //print message after email sent
    echo $send_email?"<h1> Mail Sent</h1>":"<h1> Mail not SEND</h1>";

} else {
    echo "No Data Found";
}
```

I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! :) It worked perrrfect for me . But I needed to modify my function a bit : 
`var doc = new jsPDF('p','mm');   
                    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
                    var pdf = btoa(doc.output());
                    $.post("sendmail.php", 
                    {
                        data: pdf
                    }, function (response,status) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });`