# jsPDF send on email

Tags: php, jspdf

Can you explain on the subject of jsPDF? How to send generated pdf file to the mailbox using PHP
I was trying to do in this example [html2canvas and jsPDF : send generated pdf as email attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994282/html2canvas-and-jspdf-send-generated-pdf-as-email-attachment)
But the mail comes only : "PHP Email with attachment". And the file does not come, what am I doing wrong

Comment: Not sure how you want to send the email via PHP, but if you just want to send the pdf to the server, then you'll need to use `pdf.output()` instead of saving it locally. If that's the case, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497867/4271117).