# html2canvas and jsPDF (generated PDF as email Attachment)

Tags: php, email, jspdf, html2canvas

I want to send generated PDF in a mail attachment.

I am able to download it locally but I want to email the PDF without even downloading.

I found some help on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994282/html2canvas-and-jspdf-send-generated-pdf-as-email-attachment). But it only shows the message,  not the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

Download their repo [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), extract the archive and copy the script's folder to your project. Include the main script file with

```
require_once('path/to/file/class.phpmailer.php');
```

Now, sending emails with attachments goes from being insanely difficult to incredibly easy:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

It's just that one line `$email->AddAttachment();`, you couldn't ask for any easier.

If you do it with PHP's `mail()` function, you'll be writing stacks of code, and you'll probably have lots of really difficult to find bugs.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but i want to send email with PDF attachment directly without saving it to any location in client desktop.